# iOS: change the height of UISegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to change the height of UISegmentedcontrol, but it is not allowed in the Interface Builder. Is there any way to change or it is impossible?

Thanks

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, you can use `[mySegmentedControl setFrame:frame]` in code. It is unfortunate that you can't do this in IB.

So, if you just want to change the height:

```
CGRect frame= mySegmentedControl.frame;
[mySegmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, fNewHeight)];
```

Comment: Works fine in IOS7 as long as you do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews (or, presumably, later), not in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Not working on iOS 7.1 - I've tried it out in boath viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidLoad

Comment: Heh..., works in iOS 7.1.1 and also in viewDidLoad. The only option if you don't want to use auto layout.

Comment: it's doesnt work in ios 7.1 . it's good to see any with solution of it.

Comment: Excellent - any mechanism that helps me avoid setting constraints is a plus.

Answer (score 148):

Adding a constraint in IB will also do the trick:

[image: Constraint in IB]

Comment: How do you add "blue" constraints

Comment: Select the Segmented Control in the XIB, Editor->Pin->height

Comment: Works for iOS8+ but not for iOS7.0+. In my app the segmented control sometimes changes its height back to  the default value 28. I have also implemented - (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize {
    
    CGSize defaultSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return CGSizeMake(defaultSize.width, 35);
}

with the height 35 (so that NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint for height is the same as NSLayoutConstraint) but still the control sometimes jumps back to the default height 28.

Comment: This is the best Answer. I tried it on 8.4 and 9.0, and they both worked! Many thanks

Comment: Right underneath the storyboard screen itself,  next to w Any hAny, there are 4 bottoms. Click on the second one from the right and set height as a different value. Then reset frames for that object using the first one from the right. Then you see the segmented control's height has been adjusted in Storyboard.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that no matter how high the segmented control is, the text in the segment will not go on the second line, 3rd. It will be truncated.

Answer (score 27):

Add a new height constraint and set its value.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Auto Layout and are having trouble with [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027824/575162), this worked perfectly for me:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:mySegmentedControl
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:nil
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                     multiplier:1 
                                     constant:fNewHeight];
[mySegmentedControl addConstraint:constraint];
```

Comment: This one is the only one that worked for me in iOS 7.1. Awesome answer!

Answer (score 10):

To do it inside Interface Builder you can select the control and add frame attribute under "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

[image: add frame attribute inside IB]

Answer (score 9):

Best and simple way to do is set height constraint to segmented control and increase its value as you needed.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that no matter how high the segmented control is the text in the segment will not go on the second line. It will be truncated.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 IBInspectable Solution :

```
@IBDesignable class MySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 29 {
        didSet {
            let centerSave = center
            frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: height)
            center = centerSave
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I create new swift file and copy-paste your code. Worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just Go to **Storyboard** where id UisegmentContrrole is located and set **height constraint** with your custom **heights** as

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Fortunately you can change the height from the `xib` as well**.

You can do so through the `xib` as well. Just add a segment control into the `xib`. Then open the `xib` in TextEdit. There you will find the code :

```
<segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="plain" selectedSegmentIndex="0" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="B99-Tt-vJG">

<rect key="frame" x="222" y="82" width="123" height="44"/>
```

Here you change the height from 44 to any required height. You can change the height of any `UIConponent` like this. Even for the `UIPickerView`.

Comment: The interface builder shows it with the correct new size, however it returns to its default size on runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Swift Solution:

```
segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: segmentedControl.frame.origin.x, y: segmentedControl.frame.origin.y, width: segmentedControl.frame.size.width, height: 40);
```

sets the height of the SegmentedControl to 40.

Answer (score 2):

Swift Solution:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: segment.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: segment.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    segment.frame = rect
}
```

or

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let rect = CGRect(origin: segment.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: segment.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    segment.frame = rect
}
```

or

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let rect = CGRect(origin: segment.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: segment.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    segment.frame = rect
}
```

Sets the height of the SegmentedControl to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `MySegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(15,5, 290, 50);` and just change coordinates to fit it for your view
 (This is updated for iOS 7)

Answer (score 0):

If you select the "Use Auto Layout" , reset frame doesn't work, you should change the constraints instead.  Perhaps it is the reason why the best answer not work for somebody ,  because it is selected by default in xcode 5

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Ji Fang did not work for me. I had to subclass the segmented control and add these methods. The solution based on auto layout is not robust in iOS7.0 /7.1. Sometimes it jumps back to the default height.

```
const static CGFloat kViewHeight = 35;

- (void) layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, kViewHeight)];

}

- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize {

    CGSize defaultSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return CGSizeMake(defaultSize.width, kViewHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following:

```
segmentedControll.addConstraint(
        NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: segmentedControll,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 40.0
        )
    )
```

Comment: Code dumping is usually discouraged here on StackOverflow.  Some explanation behind what the code is doing wouldn't come amiss.

Answer (score -1):

For me solution was:-

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake (20, 20, 180, 50);
self.segmentedControl.frame = frame;
```

It works in every version and without even using autoresizing.