# Change the height of UISegmented Control using IB?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

How can i change the height of UISegmented control. I'm using Swift 3.0 with xcode 8. Height property is disabled by default.

Comment: What hav you tried ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027608/ios-change-the-height-of-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: change the height of UISegmentedcontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027608/ios-change-the-height-of-uisegmentedcontrol)

Comment: I've tried to put autolayout constraint on it but the text then goes upside and do not stays in the middle. @UmairAfzal

Comment: I've cheched that question but i wanna know if it's possible using Interface builder without any programming bucks. @kennytm

Comment: @Peeyushkarnwal You should tell us what have you tried with some code or screenshot.

Comment: add height constraint for segment control and give constant value as per your requirement.

Comment: This link may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027608/ios-change-the-height-of-uisegmentedcontrol/41889155#41889155

Answer (score 4):

I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889155/7652057

```
@IBDesignable class MySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

@IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 29 {
    didSet {
        let centerSave = center
        frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: height)
        center = centerSave
    }
}
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716960/7652057

One of three options from the link,

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
let rect = CGRect(origin: segment.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: segment.frame.size.width, height: 100))
segment.frame = rect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was trying to do it for a long while and here is the solution.
Firstly, **It is possible within IB but for that we need to have a good bunch of autolayout constraints.**

**I've placed that Segmented control in a UIVIew with all the edges pinned inside it. 
Then I gave the desired height to that view and it worked.**
Also.. thanks to all of your answer

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy. You can access it programmaticly by using frame's height:

```
yourSegmentedControllOutlet.frame.size.height = yourHeight
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it form IB.