# How to change the height of the UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using an `UISegmentedControl` in an `UITableView` as follows-

```swift
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Segment1", "Segment2"])
tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl
```

The above code works as expected. I would like to change the height of the `UISegmentedControl`. I tried to set a height constraint on the `UISegmentedControl` as follows-

```swift
let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Segment1", "Segment2"])
segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl
```

When the above code is run, the height of the `UISegmentedControl` is set to the expected custom height. However, the leading and trailing edges of the `UISegmentedControl` do not snap to the leading and trailing edges of the `UITableView`.

I also tried to create a custom `UISegmentedControl` to specify the height of the `UISegmentedControl` without setting a height constraint as follows-

```swift
class CustomSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: 50)
    }
}
```

The above code does not work as expected. Can anyone point out how to set the height of the `UISegmentedControl` so that it appears as expcted when used in `UITableView`?

Comment: There are some classes, like UISwitch, that force their dimensions, Segmented Control might be one, your best bet is probably to recreate it to fit your design.

Comment: UISegmentedControl doesn't like to be resized manually, it's height is not under your control. Best use an alternative like [MultiSelectSegmentedControl](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl) or [BetterSegmentedControl](https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` you're losing the default constraints.

If you are happy with the appearance and layout of the segmented control, you just want to change its height, try this approach:

```
// probably in
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Segment1", "Segment2"])
    segmentedControl.frame.size.height = 50.0
    tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same question as this:
[iOS: change the height of UISegmentedcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027608/ios-change-the-height-of-uisegmentedcontrol)

By the way, you can also change the scale by changing views transform.

```
var segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: h))
segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: x, y: y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `frame` to `tableView.tableHeaderView`. Don't use constraints.

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height = 50
```